# probability (win at least k consecutive games)

Tags: probability, algorithms

I already asked [**my question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43166296/algorithm-to-find-consecutive-wins-adjusted-binomial-distribution) on stackoverflow, but got directed here (by someone who initially gave me an answer but deleted it afterwards).

His idea was the following formular: $(m-i+1) \cdot p^i$

Then I tried, to iterate over all k and sum them 
$\sum_{i=k}^{m} (m-i+1) \cdot p^i$
but this gives me the wrong output.

Does any one really have an idea, what the correct calculation for the probability is to win at least k consecutive times (also winning more than k consecutive games or winning all the time is okay, just at least k times).